# How to add CDATA in a XML without the Loss of <br/> tag in java?

Tags: java, xml, cdata

How to add CDATA in a XML without the Loss of `<br/>` tag in java?

I need to add the Cdata to the String `temp1` and also need to retain the break tag.

Then the program and sample below:

i)  program-AddCDATASectionToDOMDocument.java

ii)  input xml

iii) required output

i)  program-AddCDATASectionToDOMDocument.java

```
public class AddCDATASectionToDOMDocument {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        xmlreader xmlr = new xmlreader();
        String temp1 = xmlr.xmlFileReader("example.xml", "contentmeta","subtitle");
        String temp2 = "<![CDATA[" + temp1 + "]]>";
        xmlr.xmlFileWriter("example.xml", "contentmeta", "subtitle", temp2);
    }

}
```

ii)example.xml
[image]

iii)required out put

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using regular expressions instead of parsing it with DOM? This code may work with your example:

```
    String input = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("file1.xml")));
    final Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<subtitle>(.+?)</subtitle>");
    final Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(input);
    String modification;
    if (matcher.find()) {
         modification = "<subtitle><![CDATA["+matcher.group(1)+"]]></subtitle>";
         String output = matcher.replaceFirst(modification);
         System.out.println(output);
         FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("file2.xml");
         outputStream.write(output.getBytes());
    }
```